# Delivery Assignment Algorithm

Tags: algorithm

I have a scenario where deliveries should be managed properly with optimized route.

Let me explain the scenario in detail;

We are dealing with a company who are doing the furniture sales. There may be more than 4000 to 5000 deliveries per day and it is pretty difficult for them to assign each delivery to each vehicle and the fuel cost also not able to control. The overtime allowance also coming very high as they are not properly scheduling the deliveries. So they required an application which will handle these situations.

The application should handle following scenarios;

1. All the deliveries to be done.
2. The system should findout how many vehicles required for delivering the items with the following input parameters.

   Input 1: The delivery location (Latitude and Longitude).

   Input 2:  Percentage of space used by the item in Vehicle

   Input 3: The FIXING TIME (For items dismantled; which will be refixing at delivery 
              location)
3. From the above parameters the system should calculate how many vehicles required and which all deliveries to be assigned to which all vehicles.
4. The Vehicle working time should be 8 hours (TRAVEL TIME + FIXING TIME).

I have tried this with the help of HUNGARIAN algorithm but failed to get the proper output.

Please suggest me which algorithm will be suitable for my scenario.

---

Shenu Lal

Comment: exactly its a homework. But can you just suggest me with which linear programming section can be used for this?

Comment: Well, the idea of homework is to make you think about the problem. What is the result of your thoughts?